# There is no simple group of order 400

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory, simple-groups

> There is no simple group of order 400.

**My attempt**:

Firstly, I started supposing that $G$ was not simple, and using the Sylow theorems I got that $G$ must have $25$ $2$-Sylow and $16$ $5$-Sylow.

The thing is I don't know how to end in a contradiction at this point.

As the number of Sylows is quite considerable, I cannot use the fact that $G$ divides $n!/2$ because obviously does.

Finally, I tried to count on elements but I cannot afirm that the intersection of Sylows is trivial and even get a minimum value

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No group of order 400 is simple](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/79632/no-group-of-order-400-is-simple)

Comment: You made a big mistake:  you started by assuming what you wanted to prove.

Answer (score 0):

By Burnside's theorem it would be solvable.   But a non-abelian simple  group can't be solvable. Meanwhile if it were abelian,  its order would have to be prime.